# First tab automatically starts in the background in the tabHost in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I noticed a peculiar problem in my Android app.

Actually, in my app I am using `TabHost` and setting the current tab dynamically in runtime using `setCurrentTab(i)` where the value of `i` is coming from some other previous `Activity`.

Now the problem is that whatever I set the value of `i`, i.e. the current tab, **the first tab activity ( `onCreate()` method) always starts in background** and as I am using the `progressBar` in only first tab `Activity`, I can notice that progress bar in other `tabGroupActivity` also.
And also as I am parsing some data in First tabActivity, that is also executed in the background  and hence consuming unnecessary memory.

Any idea or help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: could you please provide more info by posting your code here so anyone can see what's wrong with it?

Comment: @  Kristiono Setyadi : The coding is just simple , and there is nothing wrong with this, My issue is that when I start any tabGroup dynamically other than the first one, the first activity start in background, how can I prevent this.

Comment: @DineshSharma well you are right.. I am having the same issue too.. Have you identified it?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I don't think it has any solution, seems like its a bug of android OS. For now we have to handle this manually...!!!

Comment: Hmm I found the same going through TabHost [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/TabHost.java#TabHost.setup%28%29)..